# How to update a cocoapod built in Swift 3 to Swift 4

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoapods, swift4

So I've downloaded the Xcode 9 beta, and I've been tasked with updating one of our in house pods from Swift 3 to Swift 4. I have cloned the repo, and opened it and can see all the project files and everything else, but there is no scheme, and I am unable to use `Edit > Convert > Convert to current Swift syntax` as it is greyed out.

On the main project, I used the migration tool and then went through manually and added @objc to expose whatever was referenced in Objective-C, but I can't seem to be able to do that with the pod.

I'm just wondering if someone has any experience on updating a pod to Swift 4, and if so how do I go about doing it as there is very little information online about it.

Many thanks as always,

Niall

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go to your `Pods` project, then:

1. Select the target you want to update
2. Go into its build settings
3. Select `Swift 3.2` as the language version

[image]

Comment: This was what I ended up doing. Thanks for your advice, hopefully others find it useful.

Comment: This is useful to make updating faster using Xcode's Convert to current Swift syntax. However the resulting updated files must be manually copied to the pod's source paths, as the Pods project is reset on next `pod install`

Answer (score 4):

The best way to do this is with a post install hook in your pod file. Otherwise each time you install/update your pods that setting will be changed back

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
use_frameworks!

target 'ProjectX' do
    pod '_your_pod_'
end

post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
            config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '3.2'
        end 
    end
end
```

Comment: I'm confused: setting the swift version to 3.2 is how you make it work for swift 4?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to change pod language swift4.0 to swift3.2 . It might solve your problem. It can be done in build settings. Search swift and change it.

Comment: Of the pod or the main project that the pod is imported into?

Comment: pod. main is independent in situation